# RSA key in env causing errors

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

Using this library..
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

I've added a private RSA key to .env. Using it to sign a JWT.
When I sign the JWT, this error greats me.

`error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line`

My RSA key is just a basic multi line, key.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpgIBAAKCAQE.......
........
```

The RSA key is multi-line. 
DotEnv can only read one-liners, the unfortunate work around (AFIAK) are to add a `\n` to the end of every line. And then make this string a one liner. But this error keeps occuring..

Has anyone else experienced this and have solution? 
Or perhaps know of another `env` file manager that can handle multi-lines?

Answer (score 5):

Add surrounding double quotes to the value in the `.env` file and replace line breaks with `\n` like so:

```
KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE..."
```